# Python Telnet Port 23 vs 223 with Different Results

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-ce, telnetlib

When I run this Python 3.1 code to access a device using telnetlib, it works as expected:

```
import telnetlib

tn = telnetlib.Telnet("15.39.100.126", "23")
tn.write(b"menu\n")
tn.write(b"0\n")
print(tn.read_all().decode('ascii'))
```

Then, I run this code (very similar to above, but this port presents different menus) to port 223 and get nothing:

```
import telnetlib

tn = telnetlib.Telnet("15.39.100.126", "223")
tn.write(b"ipconfig\n")
tn.write(b"exit\n")
print(tn.read_all().decode('ascii'))
```

When running the telnet session to 223 manually, it reports this:

```
WinCEPocket CMD v 6.00
\>
```

Has anyone ever run into something like this with different telnet behavior with Python on the same device but different ports, or does anyone know what special approach I need to take with WinCE Pocket? Port 23 does NOT use WinCE Pocket - only port 223 does. Both telnet programs run equally well from the same windows command shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `telnet` command itself does different things for port 23 vs other ports:  Primarily it implements telnet option negotiation.  The purpose of `telnetlib` is to implement the Telnet protocol (option negotiation etc) for you so that you can interact with a service on port 23 that expects `telnet` on the other end.  Since `telnet` the command does not do these things for port 223 it's likely that your device is not expecting telnet option negotiation and is being confused by the initialization of `telnetlib` (sending telnet options in-band).

The solution would be to use plain `socket` to interact with port 223.  There are lots of examples of that on SO already.

Comment: Ben, Thanks for the answer, but I am not sure how to implement what you are saying toward a possible solution. Can you elaborate? Thom

Comment: Ben, Thanks much for the update. That makes sense with my experience. In fact, I had tried some socket programming with this port too, but so far, I have not been able to get decipherable output from the socket code. I will keep trying and maybe post a question on the socket code.  Thom